# Using jQuery to snap to div on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have built a simple vertical scrollable website that snaps the view to divs when the user scrolls up or down the page. You cans see a demo here: http://dev.driz.co.uk/snap.html

The JS is fairly simple:

```
var currentScreen = 0;

var scrollReady = false;

var screens = new Array( 'one',
                         'two',
                         'three');

function scrollNext() {
    if( currentScreen < screens.length-1 && scrollReady == true ) {
        currentScreen++;
        performScroll();
    }
}

function scrollPrev() {
    if( currentScreen > 0 && scrollReady == true ) {
        currentScreen--;
        performScroll();
    }
}

function performScroll() {
    scrollReady = false;    
    var newYPos = Math.ceil($('#'+screens[currentScreen]).offset().top);
    $('.snap').animate({scrollTop: newYPos }, 500, function() { scrollReady = true; });
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    scrollReady = true;

    $('.snap').bind('mousewheel', function (event, aS, aQ, deltaY) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (deltaY > 0) {
            scrollPrev();
        } else {
            if (deltaY < 0) {
                scrollNext();
            }
        }
        return false;
    });


    $(document).bind('keyup', function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 40 || event.keyCode == 38) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if (event.keyCode == 40) {
                if (scrollReady == true) {
                    scrollNext();
                }
            } else {
                if (event.keyCode == 38) {
                    if (scrollReady == true) {
                        scrollPrev();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    $(document).bind('keydown', function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 40 || event.keyCode == 38 ) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });

});
```

However I can only scroll to the first two divs and can't get to the third one... Any ideas why this is happening? I can't see issues that would cause this that wouldn't effect the first two from working...

**Update: Sometimes you can get it to scroll to the third div (scrolling up and down until it does), but it skips the second div and then when the user scrolls up again, it jumps all the way to the top... so something weird is happening.**

**Update 2: I've noticed that currentScreen is incorrectly `2` when you scroll to the second div which is why you can't scroll to the third div. Any ideas why though?**

**Update 3: It seems that the `scrollReady` variable isn't preventing the functions from being called multiple times in places, as if you scroll up and down a few times, you find that sections are scrolled passed multiple times. Which shouldn't happen, you should only be able to scroll up one and down one at a time.**

Comment: @PratikJoshi You should try reading the question, it really helps.

Answer (score 2):

Store the values of section offsets in variable and then try, it will work.

check this on codepen.

http://codepen.io/sandeshdamkondwar/pen/veGko?editors=100

Comment: The issue with that so far is that I can't fix the scroll position when the browser is resized. See: http://jsfiddle.net/JG68S/ basically it should move the user to the correct position based on where they scrolled before resizing the screen. My example ALWAYS scrolls back to the first one when the screen is made smaller, but then fixes itself when making the screen bigger again.

Comment: If you scroll to the second screen (index of 1) and then resize the window and console log out: `screens[currentScreen]`, the returned value is `-289` so it gets confused.. Any ideas? I'm resetting the Array values on resize, but the values are incorrect. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

In scrollNext() function Your conditional checking is wrong

on second screen this condition will be false and therefore it is not moving to third screen.

It should be

```
currentScreen < screens.length
```

Comment: That's not true. Doing that will break the indexing!

Comment: Ohh yes you are starting currentScreen with 0

Comment: If you debug the code you will find the offsets are returning wrong values.

value of newPosY is going wrong because of jquery offset function.

I don't know the reason why.